# TFS 2018 Authentication through TFS-proxy server

Tags: tfs, tfvc, tfs-proxy

We are building a separated network.
All VMs are connected only to Each Other and to TFS-Proxy server.
No internet or other connection allowed
When configuring the TFS proxy on Visual Studio 2015, I have only the following option

[image: Use TFS proxy for file downloads]

I don't see an option to pass authentication and on the Team Explorer I get the error

[image: Team Explorer error message]

Setting on the TFS-Proxy itself

[image: TFS Proxy configuration]

The TFS server is on a domain OnPrem TFS version 2018.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect **through** the TFS proxy, the TFS proxy is used to cache some files locally, but the primary connection is still to the TFS server directly. Its purpose is to download TFVC files and Work Item attachments from the local network without having to fetch them all from a central server. This can speed up your workspace syncs considerably when you have branch offices with slow internet connections that connect to a central TFS server in the HQ.

You can configure your Windows machine to use an HTTP proxy in the Internet Settings and the connection to TFS will pass through that. You can use the HTTP proxy together with the TFS Proxy.

You will need to [configure Git to connect to the TFS server through the proxy](https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765) separately.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```

In all cases, you need to enter the actual FQDN of the TFS server in Team Explorer, the TFS proxy in the TFVC settings and the HTTP proxy in your Internet Settings for Windows.

TFS proxy URL entered here:

[image: TFVC Proxy entered here]

HTTP proxy url entered here:

[image: HTTP proxy entered here]

TFS Server FQDN entered here:

[image]

Ideally, all of the proxy servers involves are configured to authenticate using NTLM/kerberos and are using SSL. That should make the client configuration smoothest.

### Direct connection with TFS proxy

```
----------        |     --------------
| CLIENT |------------->| TFS Server |
----------              --------------
     |            |           ^
     V                        |
-------------     |           |
| TFS PROXY |------------------
-------------     
                  |
```

### Proxied connection with TFS proxy and HTTP proxy

```
----------               |            --------------
| CLIENT |------                  --->| TFS Server |
----------     |  --------------  |   --------------
     |         -->| HTTP PROXY |---  
     V         |  --------------
-------------  |             
| TFS PROXY |---         |
-------------
```

### Proxied connection with TFS proxy and HTTP proxy on the same machine

This setup is cost-efficient but enlarges the attack surface on the HTTP proxy.

```
----------               |            --------------
| CLIENT |---                     --->| TFS Server |
----------  |     --------------  |   --------------
     |      ----->| HTTP PROXY |---  
     ------------>| &TFS PROXY |
                  --------------

                         |
```

Comment: thanks,can the same server be HTTP proxy and TFS-Proxy?

Comment: Yes. These are just "roles". Just remember that since the HTTP proxy server will be internet facing, it may be less secure if it also runs the TFS Proxy. It has a larger attack surface, Ideally, the HTTP proxy and the TFS proxy sit on separate machines for that reason. Cost may drive you to combine them. Also, make sure that the machine has ample disk space to store the cached files.

Comment: my TFS is OnPrem , i need to access only local address , do i still need to open the SErver to the Internet?

Comment: No, you wouldn't. But in that case, you may be able to simply (NAT) route the traffic between your networks.

Comment: sorry but i do not know much about networks routing , could you plaese explain more about NAT

Comment: It's a bit beyond the scope of this specific question and better fits on serverfault.com instead of stackoverflow.Plus, its not my specialty. I'd ask our local networking guru to fix that for me. basically it's configuring your network gateway server to pass traffif for the TFS server to the other network and it's responses back. It makes the TFS server virtually part of both networks.